# jqGrid View Form DataInit

Tags: jquery, encryption, jqgrid

Hey all (I'm looking at you Oleg),

I'm looking to implement something similar to the dataInit/editoptions/colModel option for the View form.

Currently, I am returning some encrypted data in a couple of the columns of my jqGrid, such as Date of Birth and SSN#.

Then, I decrypt the data when a user chooses to edit a row, so that they may edit the decrypted version of the data.

The code snippet I use for this is below.

```
editoptions:{date:true,size:"35",dataInit:function(element) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/server/borrowers.cfc?method=decryptString",
    data: {"dataType":"dob","userId":jQuery('#borrowersGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),"encryptedValue":$(element).val().trim()},
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.length > 1000) {
        $(element).val("");
      }
      else {
        $(element).val(data.trim());    
      }
    }
  });
  $(element).datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',changeMonth:'true',changeYear:'true',yearRange:"-120:+0"});
}}
```

This code works well, however, a user does not have the ability to edit every row within this particular grid. If their permissions are not high enough to edit the row, they are given the option to view the data for each row.

The snippet above unfortunately will not be called when the View Form is initialized, and I am looking for something similar to implement for the View Form...

**What is the best way to implement an AJAX Call to Decrypt Data for the View Form within jqGrid?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it appears as though the only existing viable solution in jqGrid 3.6.3 is to use the beforeShowForm event in the viewoptions section of the Navigator...

In conclusion, move the AJAX call to this section of your code, beneath the definition of your jqGrid.

Note that there are a couple of slight changes... References to $(element) have now been changed to the correct selector for the view form, in my case $("#v_dob span"). For others, it will be $("v_fieldName span").

```
$("#borrowersGrid").navGrid('#borrowersPager', { //navigator options }, { //edit options }, { //add options }, { //delete options }, 
  {beforeShowForm:function(form) { 
    $.ajax({
              url: "/server/borrowers.cfc?method=decryptString",
              data: {"dataType":"dob","userId":jQuery('#borrowersGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),"encryptedValue":$("#v_dob span").html()},
              method: "POST",
              success: function(data) {
                if (data.length > 1000) {
                  $("#v_dob span").html("");
                }
                else {
                  $("#v_dob span").html(data.trim());   
                }
              }
          });
  } // view options
);
```